# Script wont work with table tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that I need to total up the value of input boxes and then take those values and dynamically populate the sub total, taxes and grand total. 
My issue is that the jQuery script will not work when the form has the table tag, if I remove the table tag from the form the script will work fine. Do I need to add/remove something from the jQuery script?

```js
$(".qty").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var unitVal = self.next().val();
  self.next().next().val(unitVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});

$(".unit").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var qtyVal = self.prev().val();
  self.next().val(qtyVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});

function fnAlltotal() {
  var total = 0
  $(".amount").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $(".result").val(total);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.result {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #174C68;
}

input {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
      <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="auto-style1">Sub Total</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="result" style="width: 190px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: In `$(".qty").on("input")`, you have `self` referring to the input element. Then `self.next()` is... nothing. You need to improve your DOM traversal, for instance using `self.closest("tr")` to get to the containing row, then `.find(".unit")` to get the unit input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not finding the right elements

When you do `.next` or `.prev` it targets the next/prev sibling but since you put this in a table, there is no next or prev sibling.

What I have done is traverse up the dom to the closest `tr` then finding the other input and the subtotal

Here is the documentation of what `closest()` does 
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Take a look below

```js
$(".qty").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var parentTr = self.closest("tr"); 
  var unitVal = parentTr.find(".unit").val();
  parentTr.find(".amount").val(unitVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});

$(".unit").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var parentTr = self.closest("tr");
  var qtyVal = parentTr.find(".qty").val();
  parentTr.find(".amount").val(qtyVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});

function fnAlltotal() {
  var total = 0
  $(".amount").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $(".result").val(total);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.result {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #174C68;
}

input {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
      <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="unit"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' class='amount' style="width: 190px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="auto-style1">Sub Total</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="result" style="width: 190px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use parent and children methods as below.

```
$(".qty").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var unitVal = self.parent().next().children('.unit').val();
  self.parent().next().next().children('input').val(unitVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});

$(".unit").on('input', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var qtyVal = self.parent().prev().children('.qty').val();
  self.parent().next().children('input').val(qtyVal * self.val());
  fnAlltotal();
});
```

check out this plunker https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxVPgY